# LWUIT - How to get a 9 part image to stretch and not repeat (resource editor 1.5)

Tags: button, lwuit, lwuit-resource-editor

Is there a way either through code or the Lwuit Recourse Editor to stretch 9 part images to prevent repeating?  Ideally I would not want to stretch a single pixel but would not be a huge deal if there was not the choice.

**Currently:** I have made a few border generated 9 part buttons using the Lwuit Resource Editor.  After making the `Button` I noticed that the areas that should stretch are instead being repeated making my gradients look terrible.

**Goal:**
I am looking to make all my 9 part images (borders, `Buttons`, etc.) to stretch the Center pieces as references below.

```
* = Fixed size  
- = Stretched  
| = Image separation
```

Current:

```
* | * | *  
* | * | *  
* | * | *
```

Want:

```
* | - | *  
- | - | -  
* | - | *
```

Answer (score 1):

You must take a look at [this youtube video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LFClNS5vWQs&list=UUb-4T86pwSFyN66s7QJI90A&index=60&feature=plcp).

It helped me a lot to build my own borders to my `Containers`. You can download it from the [LWUIT repository](https://svn.java.net/svn/lwuit-incubator~svn/trunk/vprise).
Here you can find this project, and its .res, wich will help you a lot building borders to your `Components`.

Answer (score 1):

LWUIT had the initial work for scaled borders but I never completed it due to the fact that on the fly scaling just isn't supported on J2ME devices. [Codename One](http://www.codenameone.com/) supports this type of image border but doesn't expose it in the GUI builder both due to complexity and performance.

For most designs you can reach a very similar effect with the traditional 9-piece border when they are created as multi-image components.